# Compute the condition number of the matrix and show for what $\Delta x$ it is singular

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the laplacian $N \times N$ matrix 
\begin{align*}
A=\frac{1}{(\Delta x)^2}\begin{pmatrix}
2&-1& & &\\
-1&2&-1& &\\
 &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\\
 & &-1&2&-1\\
 & & &-1&2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Compute the condition number of the matrix and for what $\Delta x$ it is singular.

What I already know:

I know that the eigenvalues of the matrix are equal to $\lambda_k=\frac{1}{(\Delta x)^2}(2-2\cos(\pi k \Delta x))$ and I know since the Matrix is symmetrical the condition number of the matrix is equal to $\frac{|\lambda_{max}|}{|\lambda_{min}|}$.

But how do get a nice expression for the condition number and how am I supposed to calculate for what $\Delta x$ the matrix is singular ?

Comment: Well, you can immediately read off the condition number from the eigenvalues. I don't understand the question about it being singular because it is never singular.

Comment: It is singular if it the condition number is equal to the relative machine precision of 10^{-16}.

Comment: OK, so you mean numerically singular without preconditioning. Well, what is $\lambda_{max}$ and what is $\lambda_{min}$?

Comment: You have a problem : there is no apparent link between $N$ on one side and $\Delta x$ ans the $\lambda_k$s...on the other side. The $\lambda_k$s should depend on $N$, maybe through $\Delta x$...

Comment: Indeed, presumably $\Delta x = C/N$, so that this whole thing represents the Laplacian on some fixed interval with boundary conditions.